# Effect of Rigid Motion on Gauss Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm currently attempting the following exercise: Consider a regular surface $S$ and a rigid motion $f$. How does the Gauss curvature of $f(S)$ compare to that of $S$?

I would like to know if my reasoning is on the right track. My understanding is that the Gauss curvature at a point $p \in S$ should be the same as at $f(p) \in f(S)$. Now trying in trying to show this my plan has been to choose a parametrisation of $S$ and calculate the Gauss curvature in both cases, but this seems to be a lengthy computation. Should I be doing something else that is quicker or simpler? I'm using that a rigid motion is of the form $f(x) = Ax + q$ where $q$ is a translation and $A$ is an orthogonal matrix.

The next part of the exercise then asks to show how the Gauss curvature changes under a dilation: $f(p) = kp$ for all $p \in S$. I am planning on using the same approach here.

Comment: Rigid motions are (often by definition) isometries of Euclidean space (i.e. they preserve the metric). Have you established how quantities like Gauss curvature transform under isometries?

Comment: To be more specific, a rigid motion is an isometry of Euclidean space, and it induces an isometry of $S$ sitting in that Euclidean space. By Gauss's Theorema Egregium, it follows that the curvature is unchanged. But for the next part, you'll need a computation, although you should start by proving that lines of curvature map to lines of curvature.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are on the right track. The essential idea is to calculate first/second fundamental forms of $f(S)$ from $S$ and then calculate Gauss curvature of $f(S)$ from the formula.

This approach is lengthy (to write out) but it is a common approach.

Here are some hints for you to get started:

> Question: What is the Gauss map of $f(S)$ induced from $S$?
>  Let $N:S\to S^2$ be the orientation of $S$. 
>  Observe that if $x:U\to S$ is the coordinate
>  chart of $S$ then $f\circ x:U\to f(x(U))$ is the coordinate chart of
>  $f(S)$. Hence, the Gauss map in $f(S)$ is defined 
>  on $f(x(U))$ to be 
>  $$N^f=\frac{(f\circ x)_u\times (f\circ x)_v}{|(f\circ x)_u\times (f\circ x)_v|}$$
>  Question: Can you write $(f\circ x)_u$ in terms of $x_u,x_v$?